# Penalty for "Game Over"?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

I'm not sure where I picked up this habit, but nowadays when I play a video game, if I ever get to the point where the screen is about to announce a "Game Over", I immediately shut off the console so that the "Game Over" doesn't register.

I think I'm trying to keep my play record immaculate, in case it keeps track of how many game overs I have or something.  My question is, **is there any penalty to getting a game over in SS?**  Does it keep track of your game overs anywhere, or am I just being unreasonably paranoid?

Comment: To me it would feel like cheating, and I'll still know I'd failed :P

Comment: Death Counters went away when the Zelda games moved to 3D.

Comment: I picked up the same habit when trying to get the secret ending in Link's Awakening. The one you get by finishing the game without Link (or w/e you named him) getting a single Game Over.

Comment: Oh, yeah, the Ocarina of Time Death Count, the ultimate in determining if you have "Gamer OCD" or not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no such penalty for dying/getting a game over (aside from the fact that you died) in Skyward Sword. There is also no 'death counter' of any form.

Still, I don't think your paranoia is unreasonable! It is a common habit among gamers it seems.

Comment: In Final Fantasy 8, they keep a counter of how many times you flee from a battle. Battles are so annoying but because of that counter I never flee a single battle. Thank God there's no Game Over counter in Skyward Sword.

Answer (score 3):

When you get a Game Over you'll respawn at the last door you went through, with six of your hearts. I don't think that it tracks the number, but if it does there's no penalty for dieing a lot. You won't get any fairies, potions, bombs, etc. that you used back though, so you may want to do that anyway. An easier way to do that is to just hit the Wii button and pick restart though, since it doesn't save until you tell it to at a save point/after a dungeon.

Comment: Gah, 3 seconds too late. :(

Comment: Not necessarily half, but 6 hearts at most.  I never died when I had less than 12 hearts so I can't say for sure if it's always 6 hearts or half up to 6 hearts.